# How to do an internal POST in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to do an internal POST with IIS7/ASP.NET MVC?

Basically what I want to do is, stop processing the current request, make an internal POST request with a new body and hand over the response stream to that new request. This is required by a custom authentication flow and can't be done simply by redirects. The application built in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I've played around with various options, including `HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest` and `HttpServerUtility.Execute` , however most of them are not very POST friendly. `TransferRequest` comes close but I can't find a way to supply a new body as the `FormCollection` is read only. MVC's own `Html.Action` works only for GET methods and will not handle the result from the child action properly (i.e. redirects).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you invoke your authentication logic directly as part of your "first" action?

Comment: @usr not possible.. the user may or may not need to enter additional data after the first request is submitted, which means the original request needs to be resubmited with additional data.  This needs to be done in a way that will work for any form submission.

Comment: I understand. Can you create a client-side form with hidden inputs that mirror the POST contents that you want? I cannot think of any edge case where this wouldn't work right now except for file inputs.

Comment: @usr Yes I've thought about that as well, just wanted to know if there's a cleaner solution. The only other way seems to create a new HttpContext (which is really messy)